# Need to forward Data from WooCommerce Webhook sent to same site Wordpress REST API custom endpoint

Tags: php, wordpress, hook-woocommerce, wordpress-rest-api

I created a Wordpress REST API custom endpoint to be used as a Webhook URL in WooCommerce in order to convert the received data and then send it to a third party system, but the endpoint apparently is not receiving any data.  I tested the code by sending some JSON data to my custom endpoint using Postman and it works only after installing another P;ugin to enable Basic Auth.  I wonder if the problem is because probably the webhook needs authentication in order to be able to POST the data to the same domain?  If that would be the case I have no idea where to setup basic authentication in the Webhook setting in WooCommerce.

this is my code:

```
    function woocbz_CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
    {
        $curl = curl_init();

        switch ($method) {
            case "POST":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

                if ($data) {
                    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
                }
                break;
            case "PUT":
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
                break;
            default:
                if ($data) {
                    $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
                }
        }

        // Optional Authentication:
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password");

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        $result = curl_exec($curl);

        curl_close($curl);

        return $result;
    }

    function woocbz_order_created(WP_REST_Request $request)
    {
        $method = 'POST';
        $url = 'https://webhook.site/2e5e23db-68ef-4d03-b9ec-687309d35166';

        $data = $request->get_json_params();

        $user_data = array(
            'order_id' => $data['id'],
            'memo'     => $data['order_key'],
            'status'   => $data['status']
        );

        $resultado = woocbz_CallAPI($method, $url, $user_data);

        return $data;
    }

    add_action(
        'rest_api_init',
        function () {
            register_rest_route(
                'woocbz/v1',
                '/new-order',
                array(
                    'methods'  => 'POST',
                    'callback' => 'woocbz_order_created',
                    'permission_callback' => function () {
                        return true;
                    }
                )
            );
        }
    );
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it could be an Authorization problem, then I looked the WooCommerce webhook functions and fount where the delivery is executed: **/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-webhook.php**  I hard coded my **Authorization** header after line # 303 in the **deliver()** function:

```
'headers'     => array(
    'Content-Type'  => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Basic bmNkaWgdrGFsOiNIb25kdXJhczIwMThTUFMh',
),
```

**Now I need to find the Auth Basic token based on the id of the user who created the Webhook who is authorized.**